# While using testng depends on method the method is skipped when the base method execution fails

Tags: testng, depends

I have a unique requirement where the `method2` is dependent on `method1`.
In `method1`, I am trying to generate some of the order data like placing the orders and storing the objects associated to order placement in a list of objects, 
and the list generated by the `method1` will be the input for `method2`.

But now, due to some reasons, some order placement may fail in `method1`. When this happens, `method2` execution is stopped.

Is there any way to bypass this? Even though `method1` execution fails, we should continue `method2` execution along with `dependsOn` annotation.

Comment: Please add any relevant code so we can best help you!

Comment: You're testing two methods at once then. Create success and failure conditions in a stubbed `method1` and test *only* the behavior of `method2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **alwaysRun** attribute of Test annotation.